# How to feed numeric data into a classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, numbers, scikit-learn, svm

This may be very simple for people having experience in machine learning+sklearn, but I'm a complete rookie and I'm stuck. I'm trying to classify images into "cliparts" and "photos" based on three numeric features.

My data set (may) look like this:

```
data = (
    ("photo",   (213, 32, 2)),
    ("clipart", (453, 465, 212)),
    ("clipart", (23, 2, 6552)),
    ("photo",   (8797, 0, 872)),
    ("photo",   (67, 4325, 43)),
    ("clipart", (11, 21, 77)),
    ...
)
```

Each item contains this data: (image type, (feature1, feature2, feature3))

From the sklearn docs I get this example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()

from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1])
svm.SVC(C=100.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.001, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)

print clf.predict(digits.data[-1])
>>>> [8]
```

which classifies/predicts the last item of the example data "digits".

I think SVM is the right method for my purpose. But how do I load my data in sklearn and how do I use this to classify new images? I find lots of examples using words, but none for working with simple numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#general-dataset-api):

> The dataset generation functions and the svmlight loader share a
>   simplistic interface, returning a tuple (X, y) consisting of a
>   n_samples x n_features numpy array X and an array of length n_samples
>   containing the targets y.

So you have to construct two numpy arrays: first one with something like:

```
data = np.array([x[0] for x in data])
```

and second one with

```
target = np.array([x[1] for x in data])
```

Comment: My input data in neither a file nor a string. I could convert it to one, but that seems inefficient. Apart from that: is the structure itself suitable as it is??